# Volume group still active after disabling with vgchange?

Tags: lvm, luks, unmount

I noticed that sometimes `vgchange -a n [vgname]` seems to not close the volume group properly. This happens most often, when I actually prepare a new system and I do not know what is causing this. Consider the following disk structure (output of `lsblk -o name,fstype`)

```
NAME                   FSTYPE
/dev/sdx
+- /dev/sdx1           crypto_LUKS
|  +- test_luks        LVM2_member
|  |  +- test_lvm-test ext4
```

When I open all this stuff the normal way (`cryptsetup open ...`, `vgchange -a y ...`, etc.), do some stuff on `test_lvm-test` and then close everything with

```
umount [mountpoint of test_lvm-test]
vgchange -a n test_lvm
cryptsetup close test_luks
```

`test_lvm` disappears from the output of `vgs` as expected. BUT, if I just created this structure (see below to reproduce), mounted it for the first time and then close it the same way, `test_lvm` does not disappear from the output of `vgs`. Instead, `vgs` complains that the device for the physical volume "was not found or rejected by a filter". To remove the error from `vgs` I have to reopen `test_luks` and `test_lvm`, disable `test_lvm` again and close `test_luks` again.

Why does this happen? Why does LVM keep a handle of `test_lvm` after `vgchange -a n test_lvm; cryptsetup close test_luks`, when it was mounted for the first time, but not afterwards?

---

I was able to reproduce this behavior most consistently with the Arch Linux Live CD "Arch Linux 5.2.5-arch1-1-ARCH" in VirtualBox like this

```
# Let /dev/sdx1 be the partition to test this on

#
# Create LVM on LUKS with one ext4 volume
#
cryptsetup luksFormat --cipher aes-xts-plain64 --hash sha256 --label "Test (Encrypted)" /dev/sdx1
cryptsetup open /dev/sdx1 test_luks
pvcreate /dev/mapper/test_luks
vgcreate test_lvm /dev/mapper/test_luks
lvcreate --extents 100%FREE test_lvm --name test
mkfs.ext4 -L Test /dev/test_lvm/test

#
# Mount volume and write to it
#
mount /dev/test_lvm/test /mnt
echo "Hello World" > /mnt/test.txt

#
# Unmount everything
#
umount /mnt
vgchange -a n test_lvm
# -> 0 logical volume(s) in volume group "test_lvm" now active
cryptsetup close test_luks

#
# Check vgs
#
vgs
# -> Warning: Device for PV [uuid] not found or rejected by a filter.
# -> Warning: Device for PV [same uuid] not found or rejected by a filter.
# -> Couldn't find device with uuid [same uuid again].
# -> VG       #PV #LV #SM Attr   VSize   VFree
# -> test_lvm   1   1   0 wz-pn- 492.00m    0

#
# Mount and unmount again
#
cryptsetup open /dev/sdx1 test_luks
vgs
# No error this time
vgchange -a n test_lvm
cryptsetup close test_luks
# test_lvm no longer listed in vgs and no errors.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error messages about the PV not being found after closing the LUKS container can be disabled/removed by simply running `pvscan --cache` after `cryptsetup close <device>`. However, I still do not know whether closing the LUKS container in this situation can have negative side-effects on the data stored within. If someone knows more about this, please let me know.

Comment: So far I haven't encountered any negative side-effects using this method.